# Deploying a .NET Core Web API using Docker on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, .net-core

I am trying to deploy a bare minimum testing .NET Core Web API using Docker to Elastic Beanstalk without any success.

---

### The source code

I've created a brand new .NET Core Web API project in Visual Studio and left the generated example code untouched. After that I added a `Dockerfile` to the root of the project with the following contents:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:onbuild

EXPOSE 5000
```

[For your curiosity, here's a link to the .NET docker repo](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker).

After that I created a `hosting.json` file in the root of the project. I wanted to bind the Kestrel server to all IPs of the container. The `hosting.json` file has the following contents:

```
{
    "urls": "http://*:5000"
}
```

To make sure the app is loading that configuration file I changed my `Main` method to this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: false)
        .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
       .UseKestrel()
       .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .UseIISIntegration()
       .UseStartup<Startup>()
       .UseConfiguration(config)
       .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

[If needed, here's the documentation on the `hosting.json` file](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/hosting.html).

Lastly, even though I do not need it [according to AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-singlecontainer-deploy.html) I created a `Dockerrun.aws.json` in the root of the project with the following contents:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1"
}
```

All this runs just fine on my local machine. I've run it using the following commands:

```
docker build -t netcore .
docker run --rm -itp 5000:5000 netcore
```

I've verified that it works by visiting the url `http://localhost:5000/api/values` in my browser. It produces the expected results!

---

### AWS

Now in order to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk I've archived the entire source code togheter with the `Dockerfile` and `Dockerrun.aws.json`. The root within the ZIP file looks like this:

```
Controllers/
Properties/
wwwroot/
appsettings.json
Dockerfile
Dockerrun.aws.json
hosting.json
Program.cs
project.json
project.json.lock
Startup.cs
web.config
```

However, deploying this source bundle to Elastic Beanstalk, *using a single Docker container single instance environment*, produces the following error `No Docker image specified in either Dockerfile or Dockerrun.aws.json. Abort deployment.`

---

**What am I doing wrong? How do I get this to work?**

Comment: Couple of more hours later and I can still not get this to work. I'm sure that there is something wrong with what I've done but one thing is for certain; The error message is completely incorrect. There's clearly a Docker image specified... Now if only the message could indicate the actual error.

Comment: Did your app run normally after uploading source code and dockerfile to elastic beanstalk? For me I had to run  docker run manually by using ssh to the ec2 instance. I was wondering what did i do wrong!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this was all developed on a Windows machine, i.e. **Windows line endings**, and it seems that Elastic Beanstalk does not detect that. That explains why Elastic Beanstalk could not parse a `FROM <image>` out of my `Dockerfile` since there's unwanted gibberish, hence the error message `No Docker image specified...`.

I hope this gets noticed and fixed!

In the meantime I am using the Visual Studio plugin [Line Endings Unifier](https://github.com/jakubbielawa/LineEndingsUnifier) which enables me to right click on the file and change the line endings to whatever kind I want.

Comment: if you're using the eb cli, it uses git hooks, you might be able to get around that by letting [git control the line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will look into that :)